# Asp.net gridview update with a dropdownlist from the database

Tags: asp.net

this is the error am getting: EQMT' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value'

I am trying to update the data on the gridview with a dropdownlist below is the code.

```
protected void GridviewRecord_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int RECORD_ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridviewRecord.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridviewRecord.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");


        DropDownList EQMT = (row.FindControl("EQMT") as DropDownList);


        GridviewRecord.EditIndex = -1;
        using (SqlConnection con = new 
       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
        {  //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spEnginehours_Update", con);
            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
             throw;
            }


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EQMT", EQMT.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                LoadRecord();

        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Please put your `aspx` code off `GridView`

Comment: EQMT is a dropdownlist. So you need to give EQMT.SelectedValue instead of EQMT.Text . In which line are you getting error?